# HTML 5 и микроразметка Schema.org

Tags: html5, вёрстка, seo, schema.org, микроразметка

Есть проблема. Пытаюсь делать SEO для сайта. Наткнулся на такую штуку как микроразметка. Нужна ли она вообще? наверное да, для сниппетов и роботов поисковых систем.

Дело в том, что после микроразметки летит к чертям HTML5 по валидатору W3. Как найти выход? Есть ли варианты проще разметить данные. Видел мельком через ассоциативные массивы вроде можно как то сделать. Кто сталкивался? как найти выход, чтобы совместить и HTML5 и микроразметку Schema.org или другую разметку.

На всякий скину пример:

```
`   <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 footer-box wow fadeInUp">
                    <h4>О нас</h4>
                    <div class="footer-box-text">
                        <div itemscope>
                            <p>
                                <span itemprop="name">ДОМИНАНС</span> - экстерьер начинается с нас
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <b><i>График работы</i></b>:<br>
                                <span itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Mo-Fr, 9:00−18:00"><b>пн-пт</b>: 8:00 -
                                    18:00<br></span>
                                <span itemprop="openingHours" datetime="Sa, 9:00−18:00"><b>сб</b>: 8:00 -
                                    15:00</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>

                        <p><a href="about.html">Подробнее о нас</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 footer-box wow fadeInDown">
                    <h4>Свяжитесь с нами</h4>
                    <div class="footer-box-text footer-box-text-contact">
                        <div itemscope>
                            <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Адрес: <a
                                    href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81/@56.1341376,47.295553,16.5z/data=!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x0:0x4575d79e5a35c424!2z0JTQvtC80LjQvdCw0L3RgQ!8m2!3d56.1340451!4d47.298796!3m4!1s0x0:0x4575d79e5a35c424!8m2!3d56.1340451!4d47.298796">г.
                                    <span itemprop="addressLocality">Чебоксары</span>, <span
                                        itemprop="streetAddress">Складской проезд д.6, ЧувашГосСнаб, склад/офис
                                        51</span></a></p>
                            <p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Phone: <span itemprop="telephone"><a href="tel:+79530102499">
                                        +7(953)010 24 99 </a></span></p>
                            <p><i class="fab fa-vk"></i> VK: <a href="https://vk.com/stroymat21"> Мы ВКонтакте
                                </a></p>
                            <p><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> Instagram: <a
                                    href="https://www.instagram.com/6818mikhail/">@6818mikhail</a></p>
                            <p><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Email: <span itemprop="email"><a
                                        href="mailto:dominance2011@mail.ru?subject=Запрос_c_сайта">dominance2011@mail.ru</a></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 wow fadeIn">
                    <div class="footer-border"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-7 footer-copyright wow fadeIn">
                    <p>Copyright 2020 All rights reserved. Template by <a
                            href="https://azmind.com/free-bootstrap-themes-templates/">Azmind</a>. Created by <a
                            href="https://vk.com/taramparam">Pavel</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5 footer-social wow fadeIn">
                    <a href="https://vk.com/stroymat21"><i class="fab fa-vk"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/6818mikhail/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://wa.me/79530102499"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
                    <!-- <i href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

После разметки валидатор ругается на все изменения в коде, как раз таки по этой микроразметке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выход очевиден — написать корректный код!

Comment: 1) В span вместо атрибута datetime нужно использовать атрибут content.

Comment: 2) Вы не указали тип данных для itemscope, и такая микроразметка вообще не будет работать. Пропишите нужный itemtype, и после этого ошибки должны исчезнуть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте разметку в формате JSON-LD. Она не требует вносить изменения в HTML-код страницы. Кроме того, на сегодняшний день это рекомендуемый поисковиками способ разметки.

Подробнее про JSON-LD:
[Что такое разметка JSON-LD и почему она лучше для schema.org](https://texterra.ru/blog/chto-takoe-format-json-ld-i-pochemu-on-luchshe-schema-org.html)
[ФОРМАТ МИКРОРАЗМЕТКИ JSON-LD: ЧТО ЭТО ТАКОЕ?](https://blog.promopult.ru/seo/format-mikrorazmetki-json-ld-chto-eto-takoe.html)

Comment: HTML-код вполне может быть валидным даже с микроразметкой. Просто нужно его писать без ошибок.

Comment: @andreymal Согласен. Автор спросил про другие варианты, может этот подойдет ему больше.

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю. Дело в том что гугловская проверка пропускает этот код как норму. А вот HTML5  валидатор ругается на каждую разметку. Было бы неплохо увидеть примеры использования JSON-LD на примере организаций, время работы, телефоны и контакты в целом.

Comment: В поиске можно найти полно примеров реализации различных типов разметки. Есть плагины для распространенных CMS и онлайн-генераторы готовой разметки.

Comment: Отличная идея. Спасибо, поищу генераторы. Про них что то не подумал, уже голова к концу дня не варит)

Comment: Отлично, с помощью генераторов JSON LD быстро всё решилось)

Comment: Рад, что вам помог мой совет

Comment: Тот факт что тестер Гугл пропускает вашу разметку вовсе не означает, что это будет применено в богатых результатах, в голосовом поиске или для поиска сущностей вашего веб-сайта АПИ Гугл Знаний Граф. Разметка может не иметь технических ошибок, но иметь семантические ошибки, которые даже могут вызвать ручные действия.